# Generate forms from database in flutter

Tags: android, forms, flutter, dart

we need to create a dynamic forms with multi page and by the end of the form we need to generate pdf and send it by mail.

at the moment we have 4 forms with input and switch btn to say yes or no

we need to store all this in database if there is new forms the application download it directely

we have code all this form now manualy a page for each form, is there any way to generate forms from json or from any format ?

is there any suggestion ?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Can you share some code so we can point you in the right direction?

Comment: Until now not yet, i just finished the design into XD and i will start coding it in flutter, this is why I'm asking you as experienced user so i can work in the good way from the first time, I'm afraid to complete the design coding and i find my self facing to situation where i must restart from scratch

Comment: I have bad news for you. During your coding career you will make bad design choices and either love with them or rewrite everything. Just look at some examples and start coding. Start simple and ease into new concepts. Provider seems to be popular for state management rn. And it's relatively simple. Good luck